# Django 2.1.3 LDAP authentication not authenticating to backend

Tags: python, django, ldap

I am trying to create a django(v2.1.3) web app with a simple LDAP authentication. The code runs and i don't exactly know why it isn't working.  It doesn't seem to be authenticating the user info to the LDAP backend i have connected to. When i fill out the form it will always return with "inactive user", when i know the user is on the test server.  All i want is to just have it recognize that it is a "valid user"

I'm running it against a LDAP test server found here http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/

here are the changes i've made in the project:

settings.py

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch


AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389"
AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = {
    ldap.OPT_REFERRALS: 0
}

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "password"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(
    "dc=example,dc=com",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
]
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import render    

def login_user(request):

    email = password = ""
    state = ""

    if request.POST:
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        print (email, password)

        user = authenticate(username=request.POST.get('email'), password=request.POST.get('password'))
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            state = "Valid account"
        else:
            state = "Inactive account"

    return render(request, 'KPI/auth.html', {'state': state, 'email': email})
```

auth.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{state}}
        <form action="" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
            Email address: <input type="text" name="email" value="{{ email }}" />
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

i know the settings configuration is correct because when i run `ldapsearch -W -h ldap.forumsys.com -p 389 -D "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com" -b "dc=example,dc=com" -s sub "uid=boyle"` it will return with just the 'boyle' info

EDIT 2:

I used a logger to get this error when a user comes back as none

`Caught LDAPError while authenticating tesla: CONNECT_ERROR({'desc': 'Connect error', 'info': 'error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in certificate chain)'},)`

Comment: I see that you are using 'email' are you really passing an email: 'boyle@foo.com' or just 'boyle'? It might help to enable debug logging in Django: https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging.html

Comment: `authenticate(username=request.POST.get('email'), password=request.POST.get('password'))`  this sets the email variable to the uid i believe, i will try to debug it.. thanks

Comment: Found the debug error, don't know what to make of it, check latest edit please.

Comment: That looks like it is trying to connect to the LDAP server with TLS. Not sure why since you are specifying ldap://.. You can try setting: `AUTH_LDAP_START_TLS = False` in the settings. Looking at that site they don't have TLS configured on their ldap server.

Comment: I set it to false and it worked! thank you! Edit your answer to add that and ill award you the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you aren't using the right hostname for the server.

ldap://ldap.forumsys:389 should be: ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389

Using an ldap search tool such as `ldapsearch` can help verify if the server is responding correctly:

```
$ ldapsearch -LLL -h ldap.forumsys -p 389 -D 'cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com' 
-w password -b 'ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com' -s sub "(objectclass=*)"
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

$ ldapsearch -LLL -h ldap.forumsys.com -p 389 -D 'cn=read-only- 
admin,dc=example,dc=com' -w password -b 'ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com' 
-s sub "(objectclass=*)"
dn: ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com
uniqueMember: uid=euclid,dc=example,dc=com
uniqueMember: uid=riemann,dc=example,dc=com
uniqueMember: uid=euler,dc=example,dc=com
uniqueMember: uid=gauss,dc=example,dc=com
uniqueMember: uid=test,dc=example,dc=com
ou: mathematicians
cn: Mathematicians
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
```

If you get data back that means it is finding the user. The result: 0 Success just means that the ldap server was able to successfully *search* the tree.

It looks like the Django module has two methods of authenticating a user. The setup you have configured first attempts to lookup the record (via uid) and then uses the found DN to then bind (again) with the password supplied. As an example it will search `(uid=boyle)`, then find the DN: `uid=boyle,dc=example,dc=com`. Then it will bind to the LDAP server with DN: `uid=boyle,dc=example,dc=com`, `password` supplied via login page.

**In reponse to Edit 2 above:**

The following error means that the library is trying to negotiate a TLS connection:

```
Caught LDAPError while authenticating tesla: CONNECT_ERROR({'desc': 
'Connect error', 'info': 'error:14090086:SSL 
routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed (self 
signed certificate in certificate chain)'},)
```

If you are connecting to ldap on port 389 (ldap://) then TLS shouldn't be negotiated and can be disabled by setting:

```
AUTH_LDAP_START_TLS = False
```

In settings.py.

For security reasons its a good idea to use ldaps, and configure TLS options via the `AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS` dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for replying, and yeah it still doesn't recognize any of the usernames, i've tried so many urls and they don't seem to work even when the ldapsearch does come back.  i think it has to do with my code

Comment: when i run `ldapsearch -W -h ldap.forumsys.com -D "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com" -b "dc=example,dc=com" -s sub "uid=boyle"` it returns all the boyle info but says `# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success` does `result: 0 Success` mean that my user could come back as "none" when i authenticate?

Comment: You can use the DN found via that search to verify that you can bind with it, which is what Django will do once it finds the entry. `-D "uid=boyle,dc=example,dc=com"` that bind worked for me, so looks like it might be an issue with your code (or django setup)